# How to get response from facebook share button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api

> This is facebook share button code from facebook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your share button code -->
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

How can I get response of success or error from this?

I tried some examples but didn't got response after sharing via code.

Share button works and it also sharing the post.

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
              appId      : '1743496239724', // App ID from the App Dashboard
              //channelUrl : 'http://exampb.com/plugins/', // Channel File for x-domain communication
              status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
              cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
            });

            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
            FB.ui(
              {
                method: 'feed',
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                  alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                  alert('Post was not published.');
                }
              }
            );

          };

         // Load the SDK Asynchronously

             (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); 
                 js.id = id; 
                 js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                 }(document));
```

I tried this but its conflicting. With that share button obtained from FB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Share Dialog, but it only responds with a proper callback if you authorize the User with the `publish_actions` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: I didn't found the way. I had signed for that too and got app id.

Comment: without authorizing, there is no reliable way to get a callback. what for do you need it anyway? you should not remove the share button after sharing, maybe users want to share again.